# Weird issues with xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

when I use Xcode 6 my apps works fine. When I update to new Xcode 7 my apps It has some problems. Scrollview for news does not work. In Tableview when I tap one record Simulator or iPhone freeze. What is the problem?

Comment: can you add your crash logs

Comment: app does not crash. It use all CPU.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with Xcode 7. if your app runs on ios 9 please refer to the iOS 9 release notes for possible issues: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-9.0/

sometimes, recreating your problematic view controllers in story board will solve the problem, as in Xcode 7 the outlets in the storyboard work differently than the way they used to work in previous versions. (as someone who worked with the Xcode 7 beta for quite some time, I can tell you how annoying it can get...).